# How do I pass values from a database between pages in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created an application that connects to an SDF database. The user is given a list of movies in a cinema. The user can select a movie and press an 'ok' button.

The user should then be presented with another datagrid which contains all the information of that movie.

I've tried passing the SelectedIndex between the two pages, it sends the SelectedIndex to the information page, but it won't assign it to the same SelectedIndex.

```
 public Desc(int input_id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        cinemaEntities = new cinema1.cinemaDBEntities();
        movieViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("moviesViewSource")));

        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<cinema1.movie> moviesQuery = this.GetMovieQuery(cinemaEntities);

        movieViewSource.Source = moviesQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.OverwriteChanges);
        moviesListView.SelectedIndex = id;
```

Comment: I would use a pattern like MVVM and a framework like MVVM light to pass data between views. Here is a great tutorial. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-goeb2u3oA&safety_mode=true&persist_safety_mode=1&safe=active

Comment: Hm, kinda limited with time, both pages are made but I can't get the same row selected on each page. I think it's just the ordering of the SelectedIndex.

Comment: Just remember large projects start out as small ones. Setting a solid architectural foundation can save you a lot of time down the road. Taking short cuts can often be counter productive. Anyhow do what works for your that's just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

What to do depends on the purpose of the software, but in any case I would recommend to spend a little more effort on the architecture of your software. As you want to use WPF, you should decide whether to go for a MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) approach which is highly maintainable and has numerous advantages, but demands some time to get familiar with. The quick solution which is absoulutely fine for small or simple apllications is to code your GUI logic in the codebehind of your views and controls.

Anyway, I would create a model layer which mirrors your database data in according types (MovieDatabase has a Collection of Movies, etc. etc.). Then write an adapter to fill the model from the database.Then either use the model in your views - if you want to do it quickly - or write ViewModels to your Models (which is better) and use those in your views.

This being said, from the code you posted its hard to tell, what the problem is. Do you have a little bit more context? Why don't you pass the SelectedItem?

Comment: Well I have the same bit of code on both pages, I realise it's highly impractical but it's a short assignment. I just wanted the selection to persist between the two pages. SelectedIndex seems to store the row number of the current selected ListView. So I wanted the next page to automatically show the details for the same list.

Comment: If your ListView contains data and you set the SelectedIndex, the item is selected. Debug and see, whether the index you try to set is correct (why do you set id, when parameter name is input_id?) and your ListView contains data. After you set the SelectedIndex, see, whether the SelectedItem property of your ListView is the right item. If yes, it might get changed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the Movie object to the second page?   And then use .SelectedItem.   Why does the second page need the whole list anyway if it is detail for just one movie?